# When creating a Thread on a class called from an STAThread instance, what will the apartment state be?

Tags: c#, com, office-interop, apartment-state

I have project A and project B. Project B has a thread that does some work with Microsoft Outlook Interop. Project A is a GUI and is marked as STAThread on the main entry point.

If I call project b from within A, will the thread created in project B be STA or MTA?

I have an error "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID... An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-sync call."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All threads default to MTAs, unless [`SetApartmentState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate(v=vs.110).aspx) is called before the thread is started.

If you think about it, the thread can't share the *Single* Threaded Apartment of an existing thread.